# How to execute bash commands in Java (Raspberry pi)

Tags: java, bash, raspberry-pi

I dont know why, but I can only execute a very small pallet of commands on my Raspberry 3B from code (I cane even execute echo). For some reason, 99% of the commands that you would normally be able to do in the terminal itself, you cant do from code.

Example: I execute this java code:
 `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo hi");`

And I get this:
`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "echo hi": error=2, No such file or directory

Is there a PATH configuration that I dont have access to in java code? why cant I execute any commands to the raspberry pi from code?

Comment: `echo` is a shell builtin. So the command should really be`/bin/bash -c "echo hi"`. I would use an array for commands and be ready to read stdin and stderr, preferably in dedicated threads

Comment: Try asking your ide for the javadoc for the exec you are using.  It probably expects an array of words, not a command string.

Comment: @g00se - Although echo is a shell builtin, there is also a /bin/echo (including on a random Raspberry Pi Zero I just looked at).

Comment: If that's present, it might not be in $PATH. Clearly isn't as the command is not recognised

Comment: I just wrote a quick Java test on my Pi (which has the stock Raspbian non-GUI image).  Works for me in the sense that I get no exception and the process exits with 0.  No echo output seen though.

Comment: @Developer - what does `which echo` say on your Pi?  Does the file it refers to exist?  Is the directory in your PATH?

Comment: Can you please confirm that this is the exact line you're running? If you are running something else, even if it's just this with the command in a variable, please include this information.

Comment: @thatotherguy - so you think he's trying to run the program "echo hi" rather than a command-line "echo hi" in which the program is "echo"?

Comment: I suspect they're invoking `Runtime.exec(String[])` instead of `Runtime.exec(String)` as posted, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written some example that uses the `exec()` call. There are other methods to start processes from within Java (ProcessBuilder is the keyword here), but this example is relatively easy to understand:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;

public class X {

    public static void main(String argv[])
    {
        String args[] = { "/bin/bash", "-c", "uptime" };
        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = in.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                System.out.println("Found: " + line);
                line = in.readLine();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Some error occured : " + e.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

Basically the program executes the command line `/bin/bash -c uptime`; just an `uptime` would have done the same, but I wanted to show how to work with command line arguments for the program to start.